# How to write a manifest file for google apps script sheets add-on

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-workspace-add-ons

I am trying to publish an add-on for google sheets.

When I click on the add-on's icon in the sheets sidebar, the error message is:

*No homepage card is provided for the host app: Google Sheets.*

appsscript.json

```
{
  "timeZone": "Europe/Paris",
  "dependencies": {
    "enabledAdvancedServices": [
      {
        "userSymbol": "Sheets",
        "version": "v4",
        "serviceId": "sheets"
      }
    ]
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8",
  "addOns": {
    "sheets": {}
  }
}
```

Comment: Check out the documentation on [homepages](https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/concepts/homepages)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> No homepage card is provided for the host app: Google Sheets.

You should add a homepageTrigger inside appsscript.json that calls a function with your sidebar code:

Something like this:

```
{
  "timeZone": "America/New_York",
  "dependencies": {},
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.currentonly",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.container.ui"
  ],
  "runtimeVersion": "V8",
  "addOns": {
    "common": {
      "name": "Translate",
      "logoUrl": "https://www.gstatic.com/images/branding/product/1x/translate_24dp.png",
      "layoutProperties": {
        "primaryColor": "#2772ed"
      },
      "homepageTrigger": {
        "runFunction": "buildSideBar"
      }
    },
    "sheets" : {}
  }
}
```

Then inside your code.gs file write your function buildSidebar() {}